# IntelliJ IDEA - Open projects in same workspace similiar to "Add to currently opened projects" in pycharm

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-14

I would like to create / open a project in IntelliJ IDEA. I would want to add the project in same window. But, each time create / open a project, It opens a new instance of Intellij with new window or on the same window by overriding existing projects.

I tried - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/opening-multiple-projects.html.

I know there is a pop up in pycharm - "Add to currently opened projects" which helps. Is there anything similiar in Intellij IDEA?

Comment: you should add it as a new module , that's the only way to work on two projects on the same windows

Comment: Module adds only new file in a project. I'm looking for new project.

Comment: so, you can still add folders and files and libraries. If you're looking for a new project then either you open it in a new window or move to eclipse/netbeans.

Comment: Dont we have a way to add in same window / workspace in IntelliJ?

Comment: modules is the only way